# Apply a function on subsequent pairs of elements

Tags: r, vector

Suppose `x` is a vector, and `myfunc` is a function of two arguments. I wish to get a vector of the results of `myfunc` on subsequent pairs of elements from `x`. By definition, that vector should be of length 1 less than `x`'s length.

For example, if `x <- 1:4` and

```
myfunc <- function(a,b) {
  return(log(b/a))
}
```

Then I would expect

```
> apply_on_pairs(x, myfunc)
[1] 0.6931472 0.4054651 0.2876821
```

(which is equivalent to `c(myfunc(1,2), myfunc(2,3), myfunc(3,4))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapply(myfunc,x[-length(x)],x[-1])
# [1] 0.6931472 0.4054651 0.2876821
```

`mapply(...)` "applies" the function in the first argument to the subsequent arguments, in this case we pass `x[1:3]` and `x[2:4]` as the second the third arguments to `mapply(...)`.

Comment: I like this one the best, as it uses base R, it is general, and it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(zoo)

x <- 1:4

rollapply(x, width=2, FUN=function(x) return(log(x[2]/x[1])))

## [1] 0.6931472 0.4054651 0.2876821
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can `diff()` the `log()` of your vector.

```
x <- 1:4
diff(log(x))
```

Yields:

```
> diff(log(x))
[1] 0.6931472 0.4054651 0.2876821
```

---

Update: I more general solution uses `head()` and `tail()` to remove the last and first elements. You want to do your best to stick to vectorized solutions, which should be faster and more memory efficient.

```
myFun <- function(x) log(tail(x, -1)) - log(head(x, -1))
```

There's a *slight* speed edge to `diff()`.

```
> x <- seq(1e8)

> system.time(A <- diff(log(x)))
   user  system elapsed 
   8.42    1.28    9.90 

> myFun <- function(x) log(tail(x, -1)) - log(head(x, -1))

> system.time(B <- myFun(x))
   user  system elapsed 
   9.29    1.40   10.78 

> all.equal(A, B)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is answering my example, perhaps, but not my question in general.

Comment: @Bach -- I added a more general solution.